# MVC using methods from a helpers namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following in ~/Helpers/Helpers.cs:

```
namespace AdjusterSave.Helpers
{
    public class Helpers : Controller
    {
        // various methods such as the following...

        public void GetDropdowns()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use these in my ~/Controllers/AdjusterController.cs file by including it like so:

```
using AdjusterSave.Helpers;
```

However, I continue to get the following error when trying to use the methods.  When I call this:

```
GetDropdowns();
```

I get this error:

> The name 'GetDropdowns' does not exist in the current context.

**Edit:**

Trying to use method like so (in ~/Controllers/AdjusterController.cs):

```
public ActionResult ViewProfile()
{
    // a bunch of code like this:
    User user = db.Users.Where(x => x.username == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();

    AdjusterViewProfileInfo model = new AdjusterViewProfileInfo();

    // get name
    model.namePrefix = user.namePrefix;
    model.firstName = user.firstName;
    model.middleInitial = user.middleInitial;
    model.lastName = user.lastName;
    model.nameSuffix = user.nameSuffix;

    // end then, finally,

    GetDropdowns();

    // followed by...

    TempData["CurrentPage"] = "ViewProfile";

    return View("", _layout, model);
}
```

**Edit:**

GetDropdowns Example:

```
public void GetDropdowns(this Controller controller)
{
    // get name prefixes
    List<SelectListItem> prefixList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    prefixList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Mr.", Text = "Mr." });
    prefixList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Mrs.", Text = "Mrs." });
    prefixList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Ms.", Text = "Ms." });

    ViewBag.PrefixList = new SelectList(prefixList, "Value", "Text");

}
```

Comment: Please add exact code how you're trying to use GetDropdowns()

Comment: Why is `Helpers` a `Controller` ? Why isn't the class and method static ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @empi Edit made.  Thanks,

Comment: @SimonBelanger I am simply trying to be DRY and not rewrite the same methods in different controllers.  My intent is to write the methods like `GetDropdowns()` once, and then reuse the code in multiple controllers.

Comment: Please add GetDropdowns implementation - it may also be helpful.

Comment: @empi I have added it for you.

Comment: @user1477388 Your class should only inherit Controller if it's going to actually be a Controller, not if it's just going to help other controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. What you need to do is to create a static class like this:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static void GetDropdowns(this Controller controller)
    {
        // var username = controller.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        // get name prefixes
        List<SelectListItem> prefixList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        prefixList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Mr.", Text = "Mr." });
        prefixList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Mrs.", Text = "Mrs." });
        prefixList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Ms.", Text = "Ms." });

        controller.ViewBag.PrefixList = new SelectList(prefixList, "Value", "Text");

     }     
}
```

And, you can use it in your Controller like this:

```
this.GetDropdowns();
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to use `ViewBag` in my action "GetDropdowns" it says, "The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: What ViewBag? This doesn't have anything to do with ViewBag.

Comment: If you want to use ViewBag inside the GetDropdowns method you can do it like the code above. I edited the code to demonstrate that.

Comment: The purpose of this method is to fill the ViewBag so that I can fill the contents of a dropdown box.  The goal is to reuse this method in multiple controllers so I don't have to re-write it several times (DRY).

Comment: Is it possible to use `httpContext`?  In one of my helper methods, I am trying to use `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` but it says, "An object reference is required for the non-static field."  The header is `public ActionResult DownloadFile(Guid id)`

Comment: Thanks, ataravati.  But, when I am using `GetDropdowns();` in my `~/Controller/AdjusterController.cs` action, it still says, "The name 'GetDropdowns' does not exist in the current context."  I am including the namespace `using AdjusterSave.Helpers;` and I have changed the code as per your suggestions `public static class Helpers`

Comment: Use it like `this.GetDropdowns();` just like in the my answer.

Comment: Also, the GetDropdowns method has to be static.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Extension Methods instead inheriths from Controller:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static void GetDropdowns(this Controller controller)
    {
        // do something with the "controller", for sample:
        controller.ViewBag = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Everything you need to access on the controller you can do by the `controller` parameter.

And in your controller you can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // just call it, and the .net framework will pass "this" controller to your extension methodo
    GetDropdowns();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to use `ViewBag` in my action "GetDropdowns" it says, "The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: Everything you need to access on the controller you can do by the `controller` parameter. Take a look my edits.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this works.  However, it seems a bit cumbersome.  Since this seems like a common scenario, is there no better way to do this?  I am simply trying to reuse a method in multiple controllers.

Comment: That's exactly what you need to do. It's called an extension method. The whole purpose of it is to be used in multiple controllers.

Comment: Well, Extension methods are frequently used by .net framework when you want to add some functions on a class and use it as part of it (`obj.Method`), but remember it is still a method static. If you want to add a function that all controllers of your application should have, in this case you can create a Custom Base Controller and make your controller inherit from this one.

Comment: Is it possible to use httpContext? In one of my helper methods, I am trying to use HttpContext.User.Identity.Name but it says, "An object reference is required for the non-static field." The header is public ActionResult DownloadFile(Guid id)

Comment: Yes, just include the namespace `System.Web`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call GetDropdowns() you can:

Instantiate Helpers and call it:

```
new Helpers().GetDropdowns();
```

Make method GetDropdowns static:

```
public static void GetDropdowns()
{
}
```

and then call it:

```
Helpers.GetDropdowns();
```

You may also inherit AdjusterController from Helpers:

```
public class AdjusterController : Helpers
{
}
```

and then call it just as you did. Everything depends on what you're interested in. I guess you should not inherit Helpers from Controller and make the method static, but it's just a guess.

Comment: This is what I tried initially, but I am calling `ViewBag` in `GetDropdowns` and that causes error.  How can I use `ViewBag` in my Helper methods?